# How to add multiple dependency URLs to setuptools for the same package?

Tags: python, setuptools

There is no indication in the documentation that you can specify multiple links for the same package dependency: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi

#### Use Case --- Authentication using multiple methods for Github (Token or SSH)

Authenticating a private repo in GitHub can be done with either an SSH key or GitHub token. In `setup.py`, you can specify it with very different URLs.

```
install_requires = [
    "mypkg @ git+ssh://git@github.com/org/mypkg@v0.0.1",
    "mypkg @ git+https://$GITHUB_TOKEN@github.com/org/mypkg.git@v0.0.1",
]
```

How do I write a `setup.py` (or `pyproject.toml`) file such so that both authentication (whichever available) are an option for the user.